# How to catch a string in JSON file in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file and need to get the parameter ' fulltext ' , but I'm new to JSON and do not know how to retrieve it in Java . Could someone explain to me how caught this value fulltext ?

Here a piece of the file in JSON.

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "author" , "title" , "paper" , "fulltext" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "author": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://data.linkededucation.org/resource/lak/person/richard-scheines" } ,
        "title": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Discovering Prerequisite Relationships among Knowledge Components" } ,
        "paper": { "type": "uri" , "value": "http://data.linkededucation.org/resource/lak/conference/edm2014/paper/492" } ,
        "fulltext": { "type": "literal" , "value": "GET TEXT" }
      } ,
```

Comment: Use a JSON parser. There are many good, free JSON parsing libraries for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json library download from here **jar** dowonload form [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160212/json-20160212.jar)

Add this code in **JSonParsing.java**

```
   import org.json.*;
    public class JSonParsing {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            String source = "{\n" +
    "  \"head\": {\n" +
    "    \"vars\": [ \"author\" , \"title\" , \"paper\" , \"fulltext\" ]\n" +
    "  } ,\n" +
    "  \"results\": {\n" +
    "    \"bindings\": [\n" +
    "      {\n" +
    "        \"author\": { \"type\": \"uri\" , \"value\": \"http://data.linkededucation.org/resource/lak/person/richard-scheines\" } ,\n" +
    "        \"title\": { \"type\": \"literal\" , \"value\": \"Discovering Prerequisite Relationships among Knowledge Components\" } ,\n" +
    "        \"paper\": { \"type\": \"uri\" , \"value\": \"http://data.linkededucation.org/resource/lak/conference/edm2014/paper/492\" } ,\n" +
    "        \"fulltext\": { \"type\": \"literal\" , \"value\": \"GET TEXT\" }\n" +
    "      }\n" +
    "    ]\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "";
            JSONObject main = new JSONObject(source);
            JSONObject results = main.getJSONObject("results");
            JSONArray bindings = results.getJSONArray("bindings");
            JSONObject firstObject = bindings.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject fulltextOfFirstObject = firstObject.getJSONObject("fulltext");
            String type = fulltextOfFirstObject.getString("type");
            String value = fulltextOfFirstObject.getString("value");
            System.out.println("Type :"+ type+"\nValue :"+value);
        }
    }
```

NOTE: In JSON **`{}`** represents jsonObject and `[]` represents jsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.json/Jackson to convert this string to JSONObject.

If it is a JSONObject called val;

then `val.get("results").get("bindings").get(0).get("fulltext")`

will give you the full text of first element of bindings.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good JSON parsing libraries for Java. Try out [Org.JSON](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) [(Maven)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) or [Jackson Library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) ([Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)) or my personal favorite [Google's GSON Library](https://github.com/google/gson) [(Maven)](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson , It's easy to use.